# pyspark udf return values

Tags: pyspark, user-defined-functions

I created an udf that return list of lists (The built in list object). I saved the returned values to a new column, but found that it was converted to a string. I need it as a list of lists in order to activate posexplode, what is the correct way to do it?

```
def conc(hashes, band_width):   
    ...
    ...
    return combined_chunks #it's type: list[list[float]]

concat = udf(conc)

#bands column becomes a string
mh2 = mh1.withColumn("bands", concat(col('hash'),lit(bandwidth)))
```

Comment: use `concat = udf(conc, 'array<array<float>>')`

Answer (score 1):

I solved it:

```
concat = udf(conc,ArrayType(VectorUDT()))
```

And in conc: return a list of dense vectors using Vectors.dense.